# setContentView() not calling my LoginActivity

Tags: android

For some odd reason setContentView() is not calling my LoginActivity class. It displays the layout but doesn't read the context? I added a button and the onclicklistener and it isn't being called. Only the layout is being displayed.

This is quite bizarre I've seen to of done every single thing but the LoginActivity is being called? Is it because of the nested layout?

LoginActivity

```
    public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    @BindView(R.id.button_signin)
    Button button_signin;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        //button_login.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_signin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_signin:
                Toast.makeText(this, "test321", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:context="test.testing.core.BaseActivity"


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/f_roboto_bold"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_blue_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="140dp"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:text="@string/brandingtext" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="200dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_login_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_username"
                android:layout_width="285dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@color/myBlack"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/antiqueWhiteColor"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_password"
                android:layout_width="285dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/ghostWhiteColor"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_signin"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_oval"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/ghostWhiteColor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_register"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/f_roboto_lightitalic"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="hello321"
            android:textColor="@color/myBlack"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fui_heading_padding_bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.luxx.market.propg.luxx">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".BaseActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".core.activities.LoginActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".core.activities.RegisterActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting with BaseActivity which is incorrect, baseactivity should be an abstract class.

Put this inside your loginactivity and remove it from the baseactivity

```
    <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 

</intent-filter>
```